# Accessing Bluetooth dongle from inside Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, bluetooth

Is it possible to use a bluetooth (BLE in my case) dongle inside of a docker container?

On my host machine:

```
$ hcitool dev
    Devices:
       hci0   5C:F3:70:64:F0:11
```

Inside of Docker it doesn't find anything. I'm running Docker as:

```
sudo docker run --privileged -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I don't know enough about the bluetooth subsystem in Linux to understand what is different between the host and docker.

The `hci0` device does show up in both systems:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/bluetooth
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Mar  5 01:23 hci0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
```

Anyone try to use bluetooth inside of Docker?

Comment: You can mount the USB device in your container. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24231872/2430241).

Comment: There's an open issue on Github here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16208

Comment: You may want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24231872/275195) for a question about how to give access to USB devices.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to run `bluez` from a docker (and not only expose `hci` adapter) you need:

- To start your docker with `sudo docker run --privileged -i -t your_image_name /bin/bash`
- Make sure `bluez` is not running on your host. In my case I add to kill `bluez` (`killall -9 bluetoothd`) (and not stopped it properly as it will power down my bluetooth adapter and will not exposed it into the docker)
- In your docker entrypoint, you will need to start `dbus` (`/etc/init.d/dbus start`) and `bluez` (`/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --debug &`)

Comment: From dock container

Comment: would this work the other way around?  run bluez on the host and map the dbus socket to the container?  (this almost works, not sure what's missing)

Comment: Would this work with a host Windows? Can the Bluetooth be exposed to the Linux container?

Comment: Would this work with MacOS?

Comment: @Christopher MacOS does not use `bluez` but stopping MacOS Bluetooth service before running docker should potentially make it work. I have not tested it.

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm that what OlivierM wrote is working on me. Spent some time on Raspberry Pi 3B+ and its built-in bluetooth.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y bluez bluetooth

ENTRYPOINT sh docker_entrypoint.sh
```

and entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash

service dbus start
bluetoothd &

/bin/bash
```

`sudo killall -9 bluetoothd` is needed on host machine before before starting the container:

```
docker run --rm --net=host --privileged -it myimage:mytag
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
sudo docker run --net=host --privileged -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: Why do you need `--net=host` here?

Comment: I was tinkering on `TCP/IP over Bluetooth` via `pand` at that time, so I can `ssh`

Answer (score 8):

I found that there are two ways to do this:

1. Shared access to bluetooth between host and container.
   This mode is done by sharing `/var/run/dbus` as a volume mount with the container. This means that the container will use the dbus from the host as well. The container should not start its own dbus or bluetooth service - this should be done in the host. It makes the `docker_entrypoint.sh` script redundant. A tutorial showing this approach is available at https://www.raspberrypi-bluetooth.com/bluetooth-application-in-python.html

   Approach:

   - Install bluetooth packages you need in container
   - Make sure bluetooth service is running on your host OS
   - run your container with the volume mount and maybe with `--privileged`:

     ```sh
     docker run -v /var/run/dbus/:/var/run/dbus/:z --privileged {containerImage}
     ```
2. Exclusive access to bluetooth by the container. This requires stopping the bluetooth service in the host (otherwise the container can't "claim" it).
   This method can be followed by the answers above

Comment: `:z` will change SELinux context on `/var/run/dbus`, which will likely break things

Answer (score 1):

With help from Docker Community, I have Successfully Started DBus/Bluetooth Services inside docker container and scan bluetooth devices by adding --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN, --cap-add=NET_ADMIN and --net=host flags/permission

`docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --net=host -it debian:jessie`

Now just looking to start bluetooth service by "Not sharing the Host Networking Namespace" (customising --net=host to private network)

> If somebody got any Clue, that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: which host OS are you running?