# bluetooth in docker for windows host

Tags: windows, docker, bluetooth

My docker version is:

```
docker --version

Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61
```

My windows version is:

```
systeminfo

Nom du système d’exploitation:              Microsoft Windows 10 Professionnel
Version du système:                         10.0.17763 N/A version 17763
Type du système:                            x64-based PC
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y bluez bluetooth usbutils
```

When I run the following command, I start the 'bluetooth_in_docker' container:

```
docker build -t bluetooth_in_docker . & docker run --privileged --net=host -it bluetooth_in_docker bash
```

Inside the container when I run the following, I get an error:

```
hciconfig dev

Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: I have the same behavior with macOS: 11.1build:20C69

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on Windows from inside WSL2, but it takes a lot of steps.

- Follow https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win/discussions/310 to get
  your bluetooth working inside WSL2. Verify that you can scan for
  bluetooth devices inside your WSL2 distro.
- modify your dockerfile to install `bluetooth` as you did (bluez and usb-utils might not be needed)
- Now there are 2 options. First option shares bluetooth with container. Second option gives container exclusive control.

  1. Sharing bluetooth between the host and the container is possible by making a volume mount of /var/run/dbus and running it with `--privileged`:

     ```sh
     docker run -v /var/run/dbus/:/var/run/dbus/:z --privileged {containerImage}
     ```

     Make sure that the dbus and bluetooth services are working in your host when running the container this way.
  2. Giving the container exclusive control: in WSL2 (the host), run a docker container according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64126744/1114918

  - run `sudo service bluetooth stop` to make your bluetooth not "claimed" by the host (the linked answer uses `killall`, I think `sudo service ... stop` is cleaner)
  - use a sh script to start dbus and bluetooth inside the container
  - run the container using

    ```sh
    docker run --rm --net=host --privileged myimage:mytag
    ```