# Run command on host machine from interactive docker container

Tags: docker, bluetooth, containers

I am running and interactive docker container and I need to run system commands to makes changes to my Bluetooth connection and sometimes WiFi connection from the interactive docker terminal. Example:
`sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

When I run this in the interactive docker container I get this error

```
root@NX3:~# sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

Can someone please help me with this. How do I enable docker to use systemd

Comment: In general you run things in containers so that they _can't_ do things like control the host's hardware devices.  Running `sudo -i` on the host (without Docker) will get you an interactive root shell where you can run these kinds of commands.

Comment: Thanks @David, all my project has to happen in the docker environment including turning the bluetooth on and off. The only solution I have now is to ssh into the host machine and run the command. But I can't use that in production.

Comment: You want to access hardware (Bluetooth) on the Host from within a Container running on that Host?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868393/accessing-bluetooth-dongle-from-inside-docker