# How can I use Bluetooth within Docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have an Ubuntu container in Docker on Windows/MacOS.

I'd like to use `bluez` to communicate with BLE peripherals in the container.

`service bluetooth start`, `bluetoothd`, and `hciconfig` all fail to scan for communication.

Please let me know if there is any way to do or find out how to do this.

**Environments :**

```
Windows 10 Home -> Docker v20.10.14 -> Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
MacOS Monterey 12.3.1 ->  Docker v20.10.12 -> Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
```

**What I did on Windows/MacOS :**

```
# docker run --name <container> --net=host --privileged -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

**What I did on the container side :**

```
# apt-get update 
# apt-get upgrade -y
# apt-get install -y dbus bluetooth bluez bluez-firmware
# service dbus start
```

**Failure 1: `bluetooth` is not activated after I started it**

```
# service bluetooth start
 * Starting bluetooth
# service bluetooth status
 * bluetooth is not running
```

**Failure 2: `bluetoothd` cannot access the interface**

```
# bluetoothd -dn
bluetoothd[2292]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “JustWorksRepairing” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “TemporaryTimeout” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “RemoteNameRequestRetryDelay” in group “General”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
（...）
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:parse_mode_config() Key file does not have group “LE”
bluetoothd[2292]: src/adapter.c:adapter_init() Failed to access management interface
bluetoothd[2292]: src/main.c:main() Adapter handling initialization failed
```

**Failure 3: `hciconfig` can't open the socket**

```
root@docker-desktop:/# hciconfig
Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol
root@docker-desktop:/# hcitool scan
Device is not available: Address family not supported by protocol
root@docker-desktop:/# hcitool dev
Devices:
```

**Failure 4: Cannot add `btusb` module**

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
# modprobe btusb
（Windows）
modprobe: FATAL: Module btusb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
（MacOS）
modprobe: FATAL: Module btusb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.76-linuxkit
```

**Reference URL:**

- [bluetoothd fails with: Failed to access management interfac](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=126117): Installed `bluez-firmware`, but still the same
- [Bluetooth socket can't be opened inside container](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16208): `btusb` in `lsmod` result at this site, so I guess the situation is different
- [Accessing Bluetooth dongle from inside Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868393/accessing-bluetooth-dongle-from-inside-docker): `/sys/class/bluetooth` does not exist
- [Bluetooth module not loaded at startup](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=267428): Cannot add `btusb` module

Comment: On MacOS, Docker runs inside a hidden Linux VM, and it will be extremely difficult to use the host's hardware devices.  Can you run the application outside a container, using the OS-native facilities to access the Bluetooth stack?  The tasks you show don't look like this is a programming question and you also might ask on a MacOS- or Linux-specific forum.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'd like to run same program on both Mac/Windows.That doesn't seem to be possible... I may need to change my thinking. I was having a hard time because I stumbled on this before I started working on it. Thnx your advice.