# Mounting USB Android device to Docker container from a Windows 10 host

Tags: android, docker, adb, appium

I have exactly the same problem as [Connecting to a USB Android device in a Docker container via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563183/connecting-to-a-usb-android-device-in-a-docker-container-via-adb) but my host is Windows 10.

`adb devices` command on the host shows the connected android phone, but the same command inside the container does not show any devices.

This is how I run my container:

```
docker run -d -p 4723:4723 --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb -e APPIUM_ARGS="" --name appium0922_1 softsam/appium
```

`appium0922_1` is the name of my container. 
`softsam/appium` is the name of the image the container is running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using docker for windows or Docker toolbox?

Comment: I have the same issue, Docker for windows and running Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Because your window adb is connected.
You need to execute on window.

```
adb kill-server
```

then

```
docker exec -it appium0922_1 adb devices
```

Comment: it does not  work