# lsusb command brings no results on docker container (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am relatively new to **docker** and **ubuntu**, what i was trying to get my **adb** devices recognized in **adb** container.

I was checking some post and i found that we can also use **lsusb** to do a sanity check if device is connected or not

[Connecting to a USB Android Device in a Docker Container via adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563183/connecting-to-a-usb-android-device-in-a-docker-container-via-adb)

I have an **ubuntu** docker container,command lsusb  brings no result.

do i need to explicitly install it ?

Should not an ubuntu image have this installed by default ?
Correct me if i am wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Containers don't have direct hardware access by default. Giving a container direct hardware access would expose security risks, including the ability to escape the container.

You can give hardware access to a container by running it with `--privileged` to access everything, or `--device=/dev/x:/dev/x` to give access to a single device "x".

Comment: Can u elaborate little bit on "x"..I am relatively new to ubuntu..also my host machine is windows 7

Comment: The "x" was whatever device you wanted to include in your container, so "/dev/usb/hidde01" instead of "/dev/x".