# How to access USB ports from Docker Container on Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, flutter

I have created a Docker container for building and testing my **Flutter** apps. I want to connect my mobile device to the USB port of my Macbook and run Flutter apps directly on the device from the Docker container. But, I am unable to access the USB ports from the container and receiving this error.

[image: Error]

I am using **Remote Development** extension inside my VS Code for running the container.

The `devcontainer.json` file is attached below:

```
{
    "name": "flutter_docker",
    "context": "..",
    "dockerFile": "../Dockerfile",
    "remoteUser": "developer",
    "mounts": [
        "source=/dev/bus/usb,target=/dev/bus/usb,type=bind"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": null
    },
    "runArgs": ["--privileged"],
    "extensions": ["dart-code.flutter"],
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/workspace,target=/home/developer/workspace,type=bind,consistency=delegated",
    "workspaceFolder": "/home/developer/workspace"
}
```

Whenever I remove the `mounts` from the **json** file, it runs fine without any error.

Removing this line:

```
"mounts": [
    "source=/dev/bus/usb,target=/dev/bus/usb,type=bind"
],
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Prerequisites
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa openjdk-8-jdk wget

# Setup new user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash developer
USER developer
WORKDIR /home/developer

# Prepare Android directories and system variables
RUN mkdir -p Android/Sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /home/developer/Android/Sdk
RUN mkdir -p .android && touch .android/repositories.cfg

# Setup Android SDK
RUN wget -O sdk-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
RUN unzip sdk-tools.zip && rm sdk-tools.zip
RUN mv tools Android/Sdk/tools
RUN cd Android/Sdk/tools/bin && yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses
RUN cd Android/Sdk/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.2" "patcher;v4" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "sources;android-29"

# Download Flutter SDK
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/flutter/bin"

# Run basic check to download Dark SDK
RUN flutter doctor
```

Comment: Try this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563183/connecting-to-a-usb-android-device-in-a-docker-container-via-adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563183/connecting-to-a-usb-android-device-in-a-docker-container-via-adb)

Comment: To my best knowledge, that is not yet (Sept. 2020) possible because newer Docker versions for Mac run on a HyperKit-VM which doesn't have this feature. See [the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/faqs/#can-i-pass-through-a-usb-device-to-a-container) and [there](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/40). It should work with [docker-machine that uses VirtualBox](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/how-to-pass-a-dev-disk-device-on-macos-into-linux-docker?newreg=328fba6141aa45c3b6a000c9f06cfd9c). Though, then you could run VirtualBox itself.

Comment: @gr4nt3d you said it correctly, for mac users there is only Virtualbox way

Answer (score 7):

Currently, there is an [open bug in GitHub](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/149) about USB Passthrough. Also it was mentioned in the [Docker FAQs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/#can-i-pass-through-a-usb-device-to-a-container) that it is not possible to pass through a USB device:

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass through a USB device (or a
> serial port) to a container as it requires support at the hypervisor
> level.