# Accessing host USB device in Docker for Windows

Tags: docker

I believe this was possible via VirtualBox when using Docker Toolbox, and the privileged flag on the container, but I'm not certain if Hyper-V controlled Docker host can support this. I am ultimately attempting to access a microcontroller programmer via the USB device.

Does Docker for Windows with Hyper-V support this?

Update: so far it seems like there are only expensive vendor supplied hardware solutions for this as the possible options for Hyper-V virtual hardware is limited to SCSI drives and optical media.

Comment: Here is an example of what I believe to work for virtual box on windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-any-way-to-give-access-to-host-usb-or-serial-device

Comment: With both hyper-v and virtualbox VM hosts, you would have to be able to share the physical host's device in to the virtual machine before you could use the devices from a container running inside that virtual machine.

It may be possible to edit the hyper-v VM and set up a device share at that level. This would not be a supported configuration for Docker For Windows, so it is not something I would necessarily count on.

Comment: I looked into this myself some time back and found nothing useful. I'm also intending on using a webservice that communicates with a microcontroller device. My idea for getting around this (which I've partially done) is splitting my webservice into two separate ones - one which just handles communication over USB with the device and runs on a Raspberry Pi connected directly to the micro, essentially making it a "web-capable" microcontroller to external applications. Then the other webservice can run on Hyper-V and won't need special privileges - it just communicates with the other webservice.