# How to view USB devices in a Docker container, Windows Hyper-V host?

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

I'm trying to do this: [Docker - any way to give access to host USB or serial device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-any-way-to-give-access-to-host-usb-or-serial-device)

I want to develop an application with Ionic but I cannot see my device (or any usb, `lsusb`) running `adb devices`.

Do I need to map a USB folder to the container (like `-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb`)?

But how do I do that on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik Hyper-V cannot "handle"/forward/map USB devices. Thus my guess is it will not work in containers either.