# Using docker run --privileged to host a single USB device

Tags: docker, usb, containers

I was able to host my USB device with the help of [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-any-way-to-give-access-to-host-usb-or-serial-device)

```
docker run -t -i --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb ubuntu bash
```

This hosts all the connected USB devices.

Is there a way in which I can host one particular device?

Let's say the USB file resides in `/dev/bus/usb/002/005`. I would like this file alone to be hosted on my container.

I tried
`docker run -t -i --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb/002/005:/dev/bus/usb/002/005 ubuntu bash`, but it still hosts the entire `usb` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `--device /dev/bus/usb/002/005`.

Side note: Docker version 1.17 from the Ubuntu repository has a bug with option `--device` that does not set group ownership of a shared device in a container to the same as on the host. If you have issues for this reason, try:

```
--device /dev/bus/usb/002/005 --volume=/dev/bus/usb/002/005:/dev/bus/usb/002/005
```

Never use `--privileged` for anything except short debugging tests.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you!