# Running `screen` inside docker container to see serial output from /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: docker, serial-port, gnu-screen

I have an Arduino at `/dev/ttyUSB0` that is outputting simple strings. I want to be able to view this serial output inside a docker container.

On my host machine (Ubuntu 18.04) I am able to see the output with

```
user@host:~$ sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600

Hello! 1
Hello! 2
Hello! 3
...
```

but when I run the same command in an `ubuntu:latest` docker container I get `[screen is terminating]`.

I have tried running `ubuntu:latest` with both

```
user@host:~$ docker run -it --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

and

```
user@host:~$ docker run -it -v /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0 ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

Please note, **I do not want to run the container with the `--privileged` flag**.

Then I install required deps for `screen`:

```
root@container:/# apt-get update; apt-get -y install libterm-readline-perl-perl dialog apt-utils screen
```

**Why can I run `screen` on my host but not in my ubuntu docker container?**
What else do I need to do to be able to see the output from `/dev/ttyUSB0` in the container?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-device

Comment: @PierreB. I can see the device just fine, the problem is running `screen` and not the device connection.

Comment: My bad, didn't see you were already using --device already. I noted you did not want to run in privileged mode, but have you tested with --privileged just to see if it was working or not?

Comment: I can see output in the container with `--privileged`. But I want to connect just this singular device and not all the other important things in `/dev`