# Dronekit-python running in docker connecting to MAVProxy on host

Tags: python, docker, dronekit-python, dronekit

I am using dronekit-python in a docker container and am attempting to connect to an instance of MAVProxy running on my host machine (Mac OSX) using the following command:

```
vehicle = connect('udp:host.docker.internal:14551', wait_ready=True)
```

but am getting the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymavlink/mavutil.py", line 1015, in __init__
self.port.bind((a[0], int(a[1])))

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here? I am able to successfully connect using the above command when I run the python script locally on host but not when I have it running in a docker container.

I found a similar stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098061/example-to-connect-from-container-to-host-service) but the accepted answer did not work for me. Not sure if I need to be exposing ports or something like that.

Here is the command that I am running on my host machine to kick off MAVProxy:
`mavproxy.py --master=127.0.0.1:14550 --out udp:127.0.0.1:14551 --out udp:10.55.222.120:14550 --out udp:127.0.0.1:14552`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting MAVProxy on host and dronekit-python in the docker flask container properly connected.

Seemus790's answer in this [gitter thread](https://gitter.im/ArduPilot/MAVProxy?at=59d1050b7f323fc375f36ea9) did the trick.

Working solution:
MAVProxy on host machine (Mac OS in my case)

```
mavproxy.py --master=127.0.0.1:14550 --out udp:127.0.0.1:14551 --out udp:10.55.222.120:14550 --out=tcpin:0.0.0.0:14552
```

dronekit-python command in docker container:

```
vehicle = connect('tcp:host.docker.internal:14552', wait_ready=True)
```

The trick was the --out=tcpin:0.0.0.0:14552 part of the mavproxy command which is documented [here](https://ardupilot.github.io/MAVProxy/html/getting_started/faq.html)

Comment: Which version of OS X?

Comment: @Greenonline Not positive about the version when I made this post, but my same machine is currently on v10.15.7 Catalina. It was most likely a pretty similar version a year ago as well.

Comment: This helped out alot for the reverse. I had my SITL running in my docker, and my `dronekit-python` command running on my host! Thank you.