# How to give a docker container access to an unmounted USB device

Tags: docker, usb, software-defined-radio

I have a Realtek RTL2832U dongle for software defined radio (SDR). I would like to give my Docker container access to the device.

The [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-device) I have found so far:

1. The `--privileged` flag for `docker run`. Problem: [insecure](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/07/19/understanding-docker-container-escapes/)
2. The `--device` flag for `docker run`. Problem: the Realtek dongle isn't a mounted USB device, so I can't find a device path (i.e. `/dev/ttyUSB0`) by running `df -h`. However, the device does show up when I run `lsusb`, as `Bus 003 Device 027`.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to mount a usb device that isn't a data storage device? If so, how would I do that?
2. If not, how can I give my docker container access to this usb device?