# Bluetooth dongle access in Docker container without 'host' nework_mode

Tags: docker

I'm running a couple of docker containers on a SBC.
The containers are set up with `traefik` reverse proxy and all of them using the same network 
with `bridge` driver.

I have a Bluetooth dongle which works fine on the host, however:

```
hcitool dev
```

shows nothing in the container.

Is there any way to be able to use Bluetooth inside of the container without changing the network to `host`, because that messes up the reverse proxy and other things.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Docker is an isolation system that intentionally hides most of the hardware setup from container processes.  Try running the process outside of Docker on the host directly.

Comment: You need to mount the BT device to the container. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24231872/2879188