# Accessing external reader(smart card readers, nfc reader,etc) devices inside a docker container

Tags: docker, usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, smartcard-reader, pyscard

I am trying to make a application that uses a card reader and want to dockerise that solution.
As of now I have dockerised the application (Linux container using WSL on windows (docker desktop))but catch is I cant seem to access the reader inside the container.

To check access I am using a simple `lsusb` command after running `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`.

I have  referred following approach:
[Docker - a way to give access to a host USB or serial device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-devi)

Also I am using [Pyscard](https://pyscard.sourceforge.io/user-guide.html#pyscard-user-guide) python library to access the reader for the application.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is to make the socket `/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm` available from inside the docker container.

You can inspire from the solution with flatpak I described in [Accessing smart cards from inside a flatpak sandbox](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2022/02/accessing-smart-cards-from-inside.html).