# USB serial COM port access for IoT Edge ERROR

Tags: docker, azure-iot-edge, windows-container, com-port

I am trying to read from a modbus comport inside a docker IoT Edge module. I have supplied the relevant createOptions:

{
"HostConfig": {
"Isolation": "Process",
"Devices": [
{
"PathOnHost": "class/86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73",
"PathInContainer": "",
"CgroupPermissions": ""
}
],
"Binds": [
"C:/Streamwise:C:/Streamwise"
]
}
}

This works flawlessly on some ipcs but fails on others with a

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'COM4'.
File name: 'COM4'

when I try to open the serail port

This is the same error I receive if I dont specify any createOptions. So it appears that those options are not being applied. Any idea why?

Code snippet below

```
    public static void Connect(string portName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(portName);
        // Configure serial port
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        master = new ModbusFactory().CreateRtuMaster(new SerialPortAdapter(port));
        master.Transport.ReadTimeout = 200;
        master.Transport.WriteTimeout = 200;
    }
```

Error occurs on port.open()

Additional context:
for some reason on ipcs where I have to specify DNS server inside daemon.json for iotedge-moby, this problem occurs. Not sure if they are related or pure conincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need to map the host port to module port using PortBindings:

For example:

```
"createOptions": {
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "8080/tcp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "80"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: [How to configure container create options for IoT Edge modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-use-create-options?view=iotedge-2020-11)

Comment: nah thats for tcp/udp mapping, im trying to mount a hardware usb serial port

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-device