# Mounting and accessing USB devices from docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to mount USB device so that docker can access host USB devices from the containers. I followed the [Dynamically access USB devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758958/15610191). I have few doubts here:

1. My container is already existing so as per my understanding `docker run` command will create new container but I want to use the existing container.
2. As a try, I proceeded with creating new container following the method given in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758958/15610191) but even then USB device was not detected when I do `lsblk` inside the container.

I have used the command:

```
docker run --name testswu -it -v /dev:/dev --device-cgroup-rule='c 180:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule='c 188:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule='c 81:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule='c 4:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule='c 13:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule='c 199:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule='c 226:* rmw' ubuntu:20.04
```

I am using device major number from [Device major number](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) and added rules to start container as:

```
--device-cgroup-rule='c major_number:* rmw'
```

Can someone please let me know what I am missing here so that I can use existing container to mount and access host USB devices?

Docker running on Windows machine
P.S. I am using Docker with Linux containers and also WSL2 enabled so I cannot use Shared Drives/File Sharing option in docker settings.

**Update**

As a workaround, I have switched to virtual box with Ubuntu 20.04. Now I can access host USB devices and play with them.

Comment: Deleting and recreating containers is extremely routine.  If your current container has the wrong settings, delete it and recreate it.  That having been said, a design goal of Docker is to prevent applications from directly accessing the host hardware, and you might find this easier to do running your program directly on the host.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the update. Is there any other way to access host USB devices?

Comment: Hi David, I have added 'Update' to my original question. Can you please upvote the question so that it's no longer negative voted question? Thanks in advance.