# Passing through dynamic USB mount to docker container

Tags: docker, directory, usb

I have a Docker application that will be able to read images off of any USB via a NodeJS + React application.

I have this working natively on my Linux box using udev rules, systemd, and a bash script:

```
# Call when a device is inserted
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", \
ACTION=="add", \
RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl --no-block restart automount@%k.service"

# Call when a device is removed
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", \
ACTION=="remove", \
RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl --no-block restart automount@%k.service"
```

```
[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /some/dir/scripts/example.sh %I
```

The bash script will take the dev path (i.e., `/dev/sdc1`) and use `pmount` to mount the device under `/media/usb-mount`: `/usr/bin/pmount -u 000 -t "$TYPE" "$DEV_PATH" usb-mount`.

When plugging in a USB device, it correctly mounts under `/media/usb-mount`. However, I cannot figure out how to pass this directory through to a docker container. I have added the following rules to my `docker run` command:

```
--device-cgroup-rule="c 8:* rmw" \
-v /media/:/host_media/ \
```

The first rule comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-device/62758958#62758958) and the second rule mounts the `/media` host directory to the `/host_media` container directory.

This partially works. I am able to plug in and disconnect USB devices from my system, and I see the directories being created inside the container. However, the files *on* the USB drive are missing.

How can I see everything on the drive as well? Or is there a better way to do this?