# docker for home assistant usb connection

Tags: docker, usb

I have a Debian 11 installation with docker, I should show 2 USB devices to my homeassistant installation.
how can I do?

Details:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                          COMMAND   CREATED        STATUS       PORTS     NAMES
cf81b0453972   ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable   "/init"   43 hours ago   Up 8 hours             home-assistant

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                          COMMAND   CREATED        STATUS       PORTS     NAMES
cf81b0453972   ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable   "/init"   43 hours ago   Up 8 hours             home-assistant
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker - a way to give access to a host USB or serial device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-device)